# Are the two functions different?

Tags: calculus

(1) If $F(x) = x^2+x$ and $G(s) = s+s^2$ 
(2) If $F(x, y) = x^2+y$ and $G(x, y) = x+y^2$
I think for (1) the two functions are the same, but for (2) they are different, since for (2) they give different graphs.

 Is it correct?

Comment: What's with that $s$? It's a constant

Comment: It's a variable.

Comment: Is it $G(x)$ or $G(s)$?

Comment: G(s), typed wrong, sorry

Comment: Good grief, why so many downvotes? This is a perfectly good question, and OP has shown *some* effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is basically right*.

For (1), $F(x)=G(x)$ for all values of $x$.

For (2), there are values of $x$ and $y$ such that $F(x,y)\neq G(x,y)$. For example, $F(2,0)=4$ but $G(2,0)=2$.

---

*Technically, the functions aren't completely specified until you specify the domain and the range, but one often assumes in cases like this that the independent variables are allowed to roam over the maximal subsets of $\mathbb R$ for which the rule of assignment makes sense, and that the range is either the image or all of $\mathbb R$.